# Conditional Yup schema validation with array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, schema, yup

I would like to use different schemas for an array of objects based on a value.

```
items: [{
  name: "a"
   ...
},
{
  name: "b"
  ...
}]
```

How can I validate the item with name: "a" with another schema than item with name: "b" based on the value of name?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this? It’s exactly what I’m trying to figure out.

Comment: no sorry, I restructured my app to avoid this problem.